# Difference between installing library from a PPA on Ubuntu v compiling the library

Tags: ubuntu, compilation

Could somebody explain the difference to me between 'installing' a library from a PPA on Ubuntu and compiling a library from source?

For example - Intel have a library called MRAA for accessing platform IO in linux.

You can install the library from a PPA (which works for me) or you can compile it.

[Intel MRAA library](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa)

How does installing remove the need for compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain of this, but I believe installing from a PPA removes the need to compile because it is already compiled.

Compilation is the process by which source code is transformed into instructions which can be interpreted by the computer's processor, I.E. binary.

When you install from a PPA, I believe you're installing code which has already been compiled, thus there is no need to compile any source code.